# Why can't I see all .pf (graphics) files when using Model Derivatives API

Tags: autodesk-forge

This is how I post a new job:

```
{
  "url": "/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "x-ads-force": "true"
  },
  "data": {
    "input": {
      "urn": "BASE64_URL_ENCODED_OBJ_URN"
    },
    "output": {
      "formats": [
        {
          "type": "svf",
          "views": [
            "3d",
            "2d"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the manifest I see when the conversion is over:

```
{
  "type": "manifest",
  "hasThumbnail": "true",
  "status": "success",
  "progress": "complete",
  "region": "US",
  "urn": "XXX",
  "version": "1.0",
  "derivatives": [
    {
      "name": "XXX.nwd",
      "hasThumbnail": "true",
      "status": "success",
      "progress": "complete",
      "outputType": "svf",
      "children": [
        {
          "guid": "3c9bb37d-0385-4857-ab04-2e6e3ef6a7c4",
          "type": "geometry",
          "role": "3d",
          "name": "XXX.nwc",
          "status": "success",
          "hasThumbnail": "true",
          "progress": "complete",
          "viewableID": "cache",
          "useAsDefault": true,
          "children": [
            {
              "guid": "XXX",
              "type": "view",
              "role": "3d",
              "name": "Default",
              "status": "success",
              "camera": [
                308.925903,
                507.011261,
                625.618591,
                38.749268,
                -60.60965,
                89.572029,
                -0.27886,
                -0.585863,
                0.760922,
                1.38983,
                0.785398,
                1,
                0
              ],
              "useAsDefault": true,
              "hasThumbnail": "true",
              "children": [
                {
                  "guid": "XXX",
                  "type": "resource",
                  "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:XXX/output/0/0_100.png",
                  "role": "thumbnail",
                  "mime": "image/png",
                  "resolution": [
                    100,
                    100
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "guid": "XXX",
                  "type": "resource",
                  "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:XXX/output/0/0_200.png",
                  "role": "thumbnail",
                  "mime": "image/png",
                  "resolution": [
                    200,
                    200
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "guid": "XXX",
                  "type": "resource",
                  "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:XXX/output/0/0_400.png",
                  "role": "thumbnail",
                  "mime": "image/png",
                  "resolution": [
                    400,
                    400
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "guid": "XXX",
              "type": "resource",
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:XXX/output/0/0.svf",
              "role": "graphics",
              "mime": "application/autodesk-svf"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "guid": "XXX",
          "type": "resource",
          "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:XXX/output/0/properties.db",
          "role": "Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase",
          "mime": "application/autodesk-db",
          "status": "success"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Of course, the `Authorization` header is added with a generated token

For some reason, all I can see is that only the `svf` file has been generated. 
However, when I use the [extractor](https://extract.autodesk.io/), I get the full model with all the graphics files.

After downloading all the files in the manifest above, and rendering the viewer, I get an error, saying there are files missing (which makes sense, since I have only one file - `0.svf`)

I tried to follow the [documentation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/) as closely as possible, but it still doesn't work.

This happens with every Navisworks model that I upload not just a specific one, so I'm clearly doing something wrong.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

**Background**: the [Model Derivative API](http://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2) converts a design file (e.g. NWD) into a web-friendly format (SVF). This format is actually a collection of files, images and databases, including the `.pf`. The `URN` is just an identifier of this collection of files on Forge server.

The manifest response indicates how the translation process went and the major outputs, like thumbnail, viewables or others, like OBJ or IFC (where applicable).

Now the extractor iterate through the manifest response and list all files that are part of the `URN`, including `.pf`, it uses this [Nodejs](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs) code (also in [.NET](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-c-net) and [PHP](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/php-sample-extract-svf)).

**EDIT**

Assuming you have downloaded all files properly, you need to point to the SVF file on your folder structure. The following file ([from here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample/blob/gh-pages/index.html)) shows a super basic example.

```
  var myViewerDiv = document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv');
  var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(myViewerDiv);
  var options = {
      'env' : 'Local',
      'document' : './shaver/0.svf'
  };
  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {
    viewer.start(options.document, options);
  });
```

Comment: thanks Augusto, I guess my question was unclear. For some reason, after downloading all the files in the manifest above, the viewer throws an error, saying there are missing files. If I use the extractor provided by Autodesk, I get many more files when extracting the exact same model. It looks like I'm getting a partial list in this case, I just don't understand why

Comment: Edited the question with a more accurate description of the problem

Comment: after using the extract tool, when you try to show the model, can you share the errors you are getting? Feel free to send it privately to forge.help at autodesk.com

Comment: Sent it, with the screenshot attached

Comment: Thanks for the update @Augusto! I'm not sure however the problem is related to the right path of the `svf` file. The reason is that the 404 I get when trying to load the viewer is for another file `Materials.json.gz` **which does not exist** in the manifest file. If I use the extractor to download the bubble files, I can see many more files that are not visible in the manifest I shared above.

Answer (score 0):

I’m sorry to hear that you’re having problems.

(edit) It looks like Augusto and I posted simultaneously.  His EDIT to the original post is very likely more accurate than my guess here.

I’ll need to step through the process myself to understand what’s happening, since I don’t do a lot of coding in Forge. (It looks like Augusto is watching the discussion and will likely be testing this at his end, along with the other staff on the forge.help alias.)

It looks like you have retrieved the manifest correctly, and you just need to iterate over the URNs of the children to explicitly retrieve the remaining dependencies.  If you look at the github code from the extractor example, you will see some methods such as getManifest, listAllDerivativeFiles, and downloadAllDerivativeFiles that might demonstrate what you’re missing: https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io

(edit) It's also worth noting that the .SVF file is actually a zip-archive where the viewer will find many of the other dependencies on its own.

Comment: Thanks David! I've added a comment to Augusto's answer